# GWT & Certification

Tags: gwt, wildfly, resty-gwt

I have GWT, RestyGWT, Widlfly

**Standalone.xml**

```
    <security-realm name="AdminSslRealm">
      <server-identities>
       <ssl>
        <keystore path="${env.DBO_PATH_CONFIG}/${env.ADMIN_CONSOLE}" keystore-password="console" /> 
       </ssl>
      </server-identities>
     </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
...
    <https-listener name="httpsAdmin" socket-binding="httpsAdmin" security-realm="AdminSslRealm" enable-http2="true" /> 
...    
    <socket-binding name="httpsAdmin" port="${jboss.https.port:8553}" />
```

So I have 2 question:

1)When I send first JSON I have such error

```
OPTIONS https://localhost:8443/services/v2/admin/test net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Ok I go in browser https://localhost:8443/services/v2/admin/test. and see this picture
[image]

After I accept  this connection all work fine
How do I make the client automatically accept such a connection???

2) After this when I send another JSON I have porblems with CORS

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8443/services/v2/admin/test. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://127.0.0.1:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can I solve this problem without the inclusion of CORS on the WiildFy???

if I can help in addressing these issues the certificate? If yes. Prompt how to adjust. On Wildfly I did, but I can not on GWT SuperDev Mode=(

Comment: There is one way around testing with SDM. You'll have to use mixed content policy. But in order to load the resources, you'll have to hack the yourproject.nocache.js file, and change var hostename = [ip of super dev mode server].

Comment: I also put this class on my classpath, and use it to clobber the default version. I replace the variable with my bind address. https://github.com/gwt-plugins/codeserver/blob/master/codeserver/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/LauncherDir.java#L127